# To close popup window

Tags: asp.net

I am opening form in popup window ,when i click on close button it fires click event of close button and it closes the window but again it calls page load event of the window and popup remains open until i explicitly close it by clicking browser close button.I have checked 
IsPostback.Please help me to close the window

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that it is not being reopened on your page load event. Ideally you should not be calling a server side event to close a window. This type of action should be handled client side with JavaScript to provide your users with a smoother 
user experience.

You can achieve this by adding a OnClientClick event to your button and handle the close event via a function.